# Why kinetic energy of a system in center of mass frame is non-zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, inertial-frames

We know that kinetic energy equals to $\frac{p^2}{2m}$. If this is true and in center of mass frame momentum of the system is always zero then why kinetic energy is non-zero?
Is in above mentioned formula $p$ is for momentum  of the
system or individual momentum

Comment: Kinetic Energy isnt a vector. You only get vector sum of momentums of $dm$ masses in Centre of mass frame = 0, each $dm$ have their momentum and kinetic energy

Comment: Please let me know if my post answers your question and if it doesn't why not. That will help us better understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

As the formula $E_k = \frac{p^2}{2m}$ shows, the kinetic energy is a sum of squares of individual particles momentum.

In the frame of the COM, the momentum of a system of particles is zero, but not the energy.

It is like a sample of data with a mean = 0. The variance is normally different from zero, except if all values are equal.

Answer (score 0):

An object potentially two forms of kinetic energy.

One form, which it always has except at absolute zero temperature, is its internal kinetic energy, the kinetic energy of the random motion of the atoms and molecules of the object at the microscopic level. That kinetic energy is is due to random motion of the molecules and atoms with respect to the center of mass of the object. It is responsible for the temperature of the object.

The other form is its external kinetic energy. This is the kinetic energy of the object as a whole with respect to an external frame of reference. For example, a car whose center of mass is moving at velocity $v$ with respect to the road has kinetic energy of its center of mass of $\frac{mv^2}{2}$ with respect to the road. This kinetic energy is reference frame dependent. In the reference frame of a person in the car, the car has zero kinetic energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats a nice conceptual explaination, but Im afraid it doesnt answer OP's confusion

Comment: It answers the question as to why an objects kinetic energy with respect to the COM is not zero. I will wait to see if the OP feels it does not answer the question, and why, in which case I will entertain an edit.

Comment: I think we are interpreting the question in different ways. When OP said "momentum of the system or individual momentum" I thought OP was talking about Centre of mass of a system of masses rather than individual objects (in your Car analogy too, getting nit gritty with details, there's still kinetic energy of car's parts that are moving to be accounted for, not just Temperature). I think the question needs more clarity of what exactly is the system OP's talking about

Comment: @RishiNandhaVanchi Perhaps you are right. But a system is however one defines it.  One way to find out what an OP really wants to know is for the OP to tell us if and why an answer doesn't help. I find that an easier route than to try to guess what the OP is thinking.

Answer (score 0):

The kinetic energy is:

$$T=\sum_i \frac {m_i}{2}\,v_i^2$$
The conservation of the linear momentum is:

$$\sum_i m_i\,v_i=\text{constant}$$

and the CM velocity

$$v_{\text{cm}}=\frac {\sum_i m_i\,v_i}{\sum_i m_i}=\text{constant}$$

thus the kinetic energy of the CM

$$T_{\text{cm}}=\frac{\sum_i m_i}{2}\,v_{\text{cm}}^2=\text{constant}$$

so even if  the total energy $~T$ is not constant ,the center of mass energy is constant, this is due to the conservation of the linear momentum.

Remark:

the linear momentum is $~p_i=m_i\,v_i$